# How to incorporate a batch file with vb.net

Tags: vb.net, windows-7

I wanted to make mysql dump files using a batch file and an app made through visual studio 2008.
How can I incorporate this batch file or call it from vb?
There is a code like this in vb.net but its using an absolute address:

```
Process.Start("C:exe\execute.exe")
```

How do I modify this so that I could just execute the file without providing the exact address. Or is there any place in the file system(windows 7) where I could just copy the exe file and just call it this way?

```
Process.Start("execute.exe")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You could copy execute.exe somewhere
  that's within your PATH environment
  variable.
- Your .net code could use [System.IO.Directory.SetCurrentDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.setcurrentdirectory.aspx) to change the working directory at run time
- You could right click on a shortcut to your .net script and set the "Run in" box to somewhere where your execute.exe is.
- You could ship the two together so that they'll always be in the same directory.